# Does OR-tools CP-SAT solver supports "reflection" methods such as x.Min() and x.Max()?

Tags: python, reflection, or-tools, cp-sat

I'm porting my old (from 2010) OR-tools CP solver models to the CP-SAT solver (in Python3). There are quite a few differences between these systems, but most are quite easy to port to the CP-SAT solver.

However, one thing I haven't found in the CP-SAT solver documentation is the "reflection" methods that the old CP solver supports, such as getting lower/upper bounds of a decision variables. E.g.

```
  # Old CP solver code
  solver = pywrapcp.Solver("Name")
  x = solver.IntVar(0,10, "x") 

  # ....
  x_lb = x.Min()  # lower bound
  x_ub = x.Max()  # upper bound
  # ...
```

One can then use these lower/upper bounds of the variable to implement other constraints. (Here's a CP solver implementing the `cumulative` constraint using `Min` and `Max` methods: http://hakank.org/or_tools/furniture_moving.py )

Does the CP-SAT solver supports these kind of reflection methods?

Comment: I don't think so, you can do `x.Proto().domain[0]` and `x.Proto().domain[-1]` though. PS: big fan of your blog!

Comment: @Stradivari Ah, that's a great tip and might be exactly what I look for!  (And thanks for your kind words!)

Comment: Hi! long time no see.

Comment: @LaurentPerron Hi Laurent! It was certainly a long time! Porting my old CP Solver models to CP-SAT should have been done long time ago, but I'm on it now. :-)

Comment: Using `x.Proto().domain` seems to work nicely: http://hakank.org/or_tools/furniture_moving_sat.py (I might tweak the model in other ways, though) Thanks @Stradivari ! If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the domain via the underlying variable [Proto](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/b77bd3ac69b7f3bb02f55b7bab6cbb4bab3917f2/ortools/sat/cp_model.proto#L44).

```py
x.Proto().domain
```

The first value is the `min` and last one the `max`.

```py
x_lb = x.Proto().domain[0]
x_ub = x.Proto().domain[-1]
```

PS: Maybe you can use the [AddCumulative](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddCumulative) constraint here instead.

Comment: Thanks. I will use `AddCumulative` as well, in another model. Building a decomposition of `cumulative` (with "reflections")  is a part of the learning process and test of what a CP system supports...