# How to retrieve lowerbound and upperbound from an existing variable?

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

In the definition of a CP-SAT optimisation model, is it possible to retrieve the lowerbound and upperbound values defined for a variable created upstream?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66264938/does-or-tools-cp-sat-solver-supports-reflection-methods-such-as-x-min-and-x) and also [this](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/8dbcd49e1bca830839b3bbb805bb0eb623e3568f/ortools/sat/cp_model.proto#L48)